# Recently started a bulking phase, why is my stomach always upset?

Tags: diet

I recently started my ***clean*** bulking phase for the winter and the first bulking phase I have ever done. I started on August 21st and my weight that morning was 164 lbs. Currently I am weighing in at around 178 and I really haven't lost much definition (gained much fat).

Recently though my stomach has constantly been upset. I never want to eat and have to force myself to do so. Below is a breakdown of my diet. Is there anything in my diet or any ideas as to why I'm feeling poorly so often?

~5000 Calories per day
[image]

*All nuts are unsalted

**A little information about my lifestyle:**

I drink at least 1.5 gallons of water a day.

I sit a desk all day and that's generally when it is the worst. While I'm at the gym It's never upset, but sitting down at work it is usually pretty bad. I'm happy with my gains, but eating this much food is really difficult.

MY SUPPLEMENTS

- [Optimum Serious Mass](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/sm.html)
- [Optimum Whey](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html)
- [Optimum Casein](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/cas.html)
- [Pre-workout C4](http://www.bodybuilding.com/store/cellucor/c4-extreme.html)

Comment: Have you considered [digestive issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whey_protein#Digestive_issues) related to the high amount of whey protein you're consuming? It would explain why it feels worse when sitting down than when you're up and moving around.

Comment: @Kate I have, but since I am only taking 1 whey protein shake during work that it wouldn't affect my digestive system. Also, I feel poorly before I consume any whey products.

Comment: Maybe you can try avoiding all supplements for a couple of weeks and see how you feel? Try drinking more milk instead.

Comment: @JordanCarroll I believe the effects of lactose are cumulative effect... your body might not be able to produce lactase fast enough to keep up with the lactose. I'm not saying this is definitely your issue, since we can't diagnose you here, but it's something that you should rule out. (*If* lactose is the problem, replacing whey protein with milk wouldn't solve your problem.. you'd be getting just as much lactose.)

Comment: 1.5 gallons of water stands out to me. That would make me feel pretty bloated. I'm also not surprised that you're always full: you're always eating. That's the way it goes during a bulk. I second the possibility of omitting the whey; it does many people's digestion poorly. And do you tolerate gluten well? This could be so many things, I'm not sure how to answer.

Comment: Simple answer is that you may just be eating too much. If it's worst when sitting down, it might simply be acid reflux through too much food. 5000cals/day seems way too much considering your size. Also, watch your kidneys whith that much protein intake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some type of allergic reaction to tree nuts. This is a very specific problem and not as general as I was expecting. Thank you everyone for your suggestions! I cut the almonds and walnuts out of my diet and I haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is **NOT** clean bulking (watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbPUOhmAYzU). Eating too much higher than your resting metabolism is definitely dirty bulking. Which is not necessarily a bad thing :)

You are having a lot of protein in your diet. If I were you I would have increased my protein intake gradually. Maybe by 10-20 grams a day each week. Digesting protein is much harder than carbs and fat. It would also help protein digestion, if you always consume carbs when having protein.

Creatine is another source of stomach issues. Try not taking it for a few days and see the difference. If that is the case, check creatine monohydrate and try having it mixed in a smoothie or with your shakes. That helps it digested better.

Comment: I've been using this same diet for over a month now and it's only recently that I have started feeling bad. Also, this article (http://extremebodyfit.com/muscle-building/clean-vs-dirty-bulk) seems to confirm that I am in fact clean bulking. I guess it just depends on your definition of clean and dirty bulking. I would say most people would agree with this article. Also, my protein intake before I started the diet wasn't much less. I have also taken creatine for several months now so nothing has changed in that area. Thanks for the suggestions though.